# G Suite: add users in child Organizational unit to Group automatically

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-classroom

When I add a new user to a child OU, how can I also add this user to the corresponding group automatically?

My scenario is that I have a Teachers child OU, when I add a new teacher, I also want to add the new teacher to the all_teachers group, so that:

1. we can send email to all_teachers.
2. all_teachers group is in the "classroom_teachers" group so that they can create a classroom.

What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Please show what code you have so far

Comment: I was hoping this can be done in Admin Console. There's a checkbox "Add all current and future users of my_org to this group with All Email setting". That's what I want, but it only works for the root OU, I thought there should be an option to select a child OU.

Answer (score 1):

On a high level, you could do the following:

1. Fetch the users of the OU via the Admin Directory service.
2. Fetch the members of the group.
3. Compare the two and create an array of users' email address to be added.
4. Add the members to the group via the Admin Directory service.

There are some script samples that will help you get started at the [Apps Script Reference's page on the Admin Directory advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory).